# Count elements conditional in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, conditional-statements, counting

I'm supposed to return the *count of elements* in `myList` base on some condition.
The condition on each `Integer` element to be counted is:

> not less than 40

```
public int count(ArrayList<Integer> aMyList) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int aInteger : aMyList) {
        if (aInteger <= 40)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Is there anything wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is there anything wrong?" Why don't you test it?

Comment: change your condition to `aInteger >= 40`

Comment: @SunilDabburi How aInteger > 40?

Comment: I updated my comment. see the question. `not less than 40`

Comment: Question is not at all clear. Please rephrase the question

Answer (score 1):

Your code will return the number of elements smaller then 40, but I assume from your text, that you want to count the exact opposite, the number of elements bigger than 40. If that is the case, your code has to look like this:

```
public int count(ArrayList<Integer> aMyList) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int aInteger : aMyList) {
        if (aInteger >= 40) // Here is the difference
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Boolean logic and logical equivalence

Supposed your condition is:

> **not** less than 40

That would be literally expressed as conditional `!(aInteger < 40)` which equivalents to `aInteger >= 40`.

#### Issue and solution

So your method is almost correct, except the condition: It counts all `Integer` elements in the specified list that are **less than or equal 40**, `aInteger <= 40`.

But you stated `not less than 40` which is equivalent to `greater than or equal 40`:

```java
public int count(ArrayList<Integer> aMyList) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int aInteger : aMyList) {
        // if (aInteger <= 40) // Yours was equivalent to: less than or equal 40
        if (aInteger >= 40) // equivalent to: NOT less than 40
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

#### Using Java 8 streams

You could also use streaming capabilities:

```java
// method-name: express what it does
// parameter: renamed simpler, also typed more generic as interface
public int countElementsGreaterOrEqual40(List<Integer> list) {
    Predicate<Integer> greaterOrEqual40 = i-> i >= 40;  // predicate: true if not less than 40 
    return (int) list.stream().filter(greaterOrEqual40).count(); // filter elements on predicate=true; then count the filtered elements
}
```

See [Java 8 Stream examples, Stream.count](https://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk-8/java-8-stream-concat-count-sorted-distinct-example)

Comment: Since the maximum result of List's `size()` will be `int` I decided to cast and corrected my code.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not correct. Check out the below code. If you need any modication let us know.

```
public int count(ArrayList<Integer> aMyList) {
    int count = aMyList.size();

    if(count >= 40){
     return count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Your code __returns the size__ of the list (even if its greater or equal 40). The OP asked for counting elements based on condition.